# Center page number in a custom style footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm trying to create a custom footer with some oranaments on the edges and the page number centered in the middle.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=gray!50,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\fancyhf{}           
\fancyfoot[L]{\raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\decoone \floweroneright \decotwo \aldineleft \decothreeright \decofourright \leafleft} \hrulefill~ \circled{\thepage} \hrulefill~ \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright \decofourleft \decothreeleft  \aldineright \decotwo \floweroneleft \decoone}}

\title{test}
\author{Test}
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum{}
\newpage
\section{section 1}
\lipsum{}
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image: page]

The only issue is that in the footer, the page number is not perfectly centered:

[image: footer]

The space to the left of the page number is greater than to the right of the page number. The number is slightly pushed to the right. I believe this is because I am using the left side `fancyfoot[L]`, but using the center `[C]` does not work at all.

Is there a way to get this same footer with the page number centered properly?

Comment: Every space counts. Try  `...\leafleft}~\hrulefill~\circled{\thepage}~\hrulefill~\raisebox{...`

Comment: @SimonDispa Thanks, I think that did it.